# Error compiling boost C++ libraries 1.54

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am very new to boost.
I needed to get the library files for one file thats used in an application that was made for me (so I can recompile the app myself).

I am able to make the boost library files, but a few of the files have an error and dont get made.

Here is the error copied from command prompt (note all I did to make the files was run ".\b2 link=shared")

Creating library bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\b
oost_thread-vc110-mt-1_54.lib and object bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-11.0\rele
ase\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_54.exp
thread.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) pu
blic: __thiscall boost::gregorian::greg_month::greg_month(unsigned short)" (_*im
p*??0greg_month@gregorian@boost@@QAE@G@Z) referenced in function "public: __this
call boost::gregorian::date::date(enum boost::date_time::special_values)" (??0da
te@gregorian@boost@@QAE@W4special_values@date_time@2@@Z)
bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc110-mt
-1_54.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: is this Windows or posix? Given you say 'command prompt' I think Windows but just want to clarify. Also, are you wanting 32 or 64 bit libraries?

Comment: Yup windows 7, should have mentioned that !

Comment: Is that 64 or 32 bit Windows 7?

Comment: 64bit, but I need the 32bit library file, so thats what I am compiling (which I believe is what compiles by default?).. I was able to compile all the 64bit library files successfully

Comment: See my answer; it removes this ambiguity. I have to build both 32 and 64 bit libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For 32 bit boost**, start a 32 bit command prompt. (on 64 bit Windows you find this in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe). Then run "bootstrap.bat" from the Boost root directory. This creates an appropriate b2.exe. Then run

```
b2 link=shared address-model=32
```

your command as before. (Although I noticed you tagged boost-thread; to build just the thread libraries, append`--with-thread` to the command).

**For 64 bit boost** (on 64 bit OS), start a 64 bit command prompt (C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe). Yes I know that looks odd but, trust me. Run "boostrap.bat" again, then

```
b2 link=shared address-model=64
```

Comment: Yup that worked!  I actually did this properly for the 64bit ones, but didnt think I needed address-model=32 for 32bit.. thought it was default?  or maybe its because I wasnt running bootstrap before each time? Anyways thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I think the fault was with your not re-running bootstrap. But I put the address model in just to be sure. + by the way, if you append `stage` to the command line then it will create separate build directories for the build types.

Comment: @Bathsheba I have done the same but still could not solve the problem. I actually post the question in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578614/building-boost-dynamically-linkable-gives-linking-error
Do you know anything about the problem? Could you help me please?